# split(//s+) dont remove whitespaces

Tags: java, string, split

I need to read alot of files and insert the data into Ms sql.
Got a file, it looks the texts are separated by //t.
Split does not do the job,  I have even tried with "//s+" as you can see in the code below

```
public void InsetIntoCustomers(final File _file, final Connection _conn)
{
    conn = _conn;
    try
    {

        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(_file);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fs);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        //String strline contains readline() from BufferedReader
        String strline;

        while((strline = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(!strline.contains("#"))
            {

                String[] test = strline.split("//s+");


                if((tempid = sNet.chkSharednet(_conn, test[0] )) != 0)
                {
                  // do something
                }   
            }
        }

        // close BufferedReader
        br.close();
}
```

I need to know where in my String[] the data is placed in a file with 500k lines. But my Test[] get length 1 and all data from readline are on place 0.

Do I use split wrong ? 
Or are there other places I need to look?:

// Mir

haha - Thank you so much - why the hell didnt I see that myself.
yeah ofc. iam using \s+ at all other files. 
but thank for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct regex is `\\s+`, with back-shashes instead of forward-slashes.

You could have still tried with `\\t`