# split not working on app engine java and yet works on my Android client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, split

The split method returns spaces and i need to return all elements of the string so i can pick the values i want. it works fine on Android but not on app engine. please help i need the html as an array of strings with no spaces. no this is not a duplicate of the other question. look am using the right regex "\s+"
    import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
    import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
    import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(name = "myApi", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "backend.abokiforex.greatcallie.com", ownerName = "backend.abokiforex.greatcallie.com", packagePath = ""))
public class RateEndPoint {
    String[] html;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RateEndPoint.class.getName());
    /**
     * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getRates")
    public MyRates getRates() {
        MyRates response = new MyRates();
        try {
            Document site = Jsoup.connect("http://abokifx.com/").timeout(0).get();
            Elements tags = site.select("p");
            String txt = tags.text();
            html = txt.split("\\s+");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
            LOG.info(html[i] +"\n");
        }
        response.setValue1(html[18]);
        response.setValue2(html[20]);
        response.setValue3(html[21]);
        response.setValue4(html[23]);
        response.setValue5(html[24]);
        response.setValue6(html[26]);
        response.setValue7(html[97]);
        response.setValue8(html[98]);
        response.setValue9(html[99]);
        response.setValue10(html[70]);
        response.setValue11(html[71]);
        response.setValue12(html[72]);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split(//s+) dont remove whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723182/split-s-dont-remove-whitespaces)

Comment: can you provide more details? how it works differently on appengine and how on android  
PS. also, unrelated to the question, you're using a shared field html there, are you sure this class is locked/created for a request and not a singleton?

Comment: its created for a request and it works just fine. the issue is with the html array that contains whitespaces. if i run the code on android there would be no whitespaces in the resulting array (html). thanks

Comment: can you provide an example? an input, desired output, and actual output on both android and appengie

Answer (score 0):

okay here is the answer. the app engine wasnt using utf-8(unicode) and so it wasnt getting the regex right. i defined it in the appengine-web xml file for it to work